# CMake cannot find 32 bit Open SSL on 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, openssl

I have a 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 VM and I am trying to compile a 32 bit application that depends on openssl and I keep getting the following error:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_LIBRARIES) (found
  version "1.0.1f")
```

I have created the following test case to reproduce the error.

**DockerFile**

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty

LABEL maintainer="Diarra_Bakary@test.com"
LABEL version="1.0"

RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    git\
    cmake\
    curl:i386\
    libcurl4-openssl-dev:i386\
    libssl-dev:i386\
    uuid-dev:i386
RUN apt-get install -y \
    gcc-multilib\
    g++-multilib
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
```

**x86_32.cmake**

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

# which compilers to use for C and C++
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER gcc)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS -m32)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -m32)
```

Run the following commands

```
mkdir cmake
cd cmake
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=x86_32.cmake ..
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: May be adding line `set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu")` to the toolchain file will help (probably, CMake doesn't search libraries here by default, and your toolchain should give a hint).

Comment: Thank you, it fixed my issue. I find it problematic that cmake does not search inside that folder.

Comment: Your (original) toolchain gives no hint to CMake that you compile for 32-bit environment. *CMAKE_C_FLAGS* are only flags for compiler, CMake doesn't try to interpret them.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix my issue by adding the following lines to my toolchain:

```
# Specify Openssl Path
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu")
include_directories(BEFORE /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu)
```

Thank you @Tsyvarev for your recommendation !

Answer (score 0):

CMake suggests to `try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR`.

Indeed, [FindOpenSSL.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake) features an option `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` which can be provided to specify the location of the install directory of OpenSSL.

Could you try something like that in your CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR /usr/local/ssl)
message("OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR is "  ${OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR})
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

message("OPENSSL_FOUND is "  ${OPENSSL_FOUND})
message("OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR is "  ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
message("OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY is "  ${OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY})
message("OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY is "  ${OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY})
message("OPENSSL_LIBRARIES is "  ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})
message("OPENSSL_VERSION is "  ${OPENSSL_VERSION})
```

Of course, the folder `/usr/local/ssl` must be tuned to specify the installation directory, where you will find folder `lib` and `include`. In folder `lib`, you will find the libraries `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a` and you will find a lot of header (.h) files in `include/openssl`.

Edit: if the intallation is not standard, then the environment variables must be set to the correct values without calling `find_package()`. For example, mine are:

```
OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR is /usr/local/ssl
OPENSSL_FOUND is TRUE
OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR is /usr/local/ssl/include
OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY is /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a
OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY is /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a
OPENSSL_LIBRARIES is /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a
OPENSSL_VERSION is 1.0.2d
```

Then, `target_include_directories()`, `link_directories()` and `target_link_libraries()` can be used.

Comment: This issue is that, I have installed openssl:i386 using the Ubuntu package manager so I do not have a ssl installation directory. The libraries are located at /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu and the headers at /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu.